# Find the rectangular regions where the initial value problem has unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the rectangular regions where the initial value problem

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{y^2-9}}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}, \ \ y(x_0)=y_0 $$

has a unique solution at every point.

**Answer:**

The given equation is
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{y^2-9}}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}, \ \ y(x_0)=y_0 $$

Here  $ \ f(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{y^2-9}}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} $

Now $ \ f(x,y) \ $ exists when $ \ y^2-9 \geq 0 \ $ and $ \ x^2-4>0 \ $

i.e., $ f(x,y) \ $ exists when $ \  \ y \in (-\infty,-3] \cup [3,\infty) \ $ and $ \  \ x \in (-\infty,-2) \cup (2,\infty) \ $

Now,

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{(y^2-9)(x^2-4)}} \ $

Now $ 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \ $ exists and continuous  when $ \ \sqrt{(y^2-9)(x^2-4)} \neq 0 \ $

i.e., either $ \ (x,y) \in (-2,2) \times (-3,3) \ $ or $ \ (x,y) \in (-\infty,-2) \cup (2, \infty) \times (-\infty,-3) \cup(3, \infty) \ $

So the largest rectangle is $ \ (-2,2) \times (-3,3) \ $ , where the unique solution exists .

**Am I right?**

Comment: The equation can't exist when $x\in(-2,2)$ or $y\in(-3,3)$, you said this yourself. Hence, your answer can't be correct.

Comment: Also, Cartesian product operation is stronger than union of sets, so in your last but two line you have the union of three sets: $(-\infty,-2)$, $(2,\infty)\times(-\infty,-3)$ and $(3,\infty)$. That was not your intent, I presume?